# How use pagination and .filter in django

Tags: django, filter, pagination

How use pagination and filtering together? I have problem because they dont want to work eachother, without filter pagination work but with filter my app have crashes. I know they are some examples how do this on stack overrflow, and it seems thaat problem is in html file but this examples arent fully understandable for me, i would be appreciate if someone would show me what i must change in my code then i would understand this better. I am currently learning Django and still i have problems with understanding someones else code, i understand very well what ive done in my code but when i see someone else code that looks diffrent than mine then i dont know whats going on.

views.py

```
def Product_list(request, category_slug=None):
 category=None
 categories=Category.objects.all()
 products=Product.objects.all()
 paginator=Paginator(products, 6)
 page=request.GET.get('page')
 products=paginator.get_page(page)

if category_slug:
    category=get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    products=products.filter(category=category)

return render(request, 'shop/product/Product_list.html',
                  {'products':products, 'category':category,
                   'categories':categories,})
```

product_list.html

```
<div class='paginator'>
 {% if products.has_previous %}
  <a href='?page1'><<</a>
  <a href='?page={{products.previous_page_number}}'><</a>
 {%endif%}
 {%for num in products.paginator.page_range%}
  {% if products.number == num %}
   <strong>{{num}}</strong>
  {%elif num > products.number|add:'-3' and num < products.number|add:'3' %}
   {{num}}
  {%endif%}
 {%endfor%}
 {% if products.has_next %}
  <a href='?page={{products.paginator.num_pages}}'>>></a>
  <a href='?page={{products.next_page_number}}'>></a>
 {%endif%}
</div>
```

Comment: What "crashes"? Show the errors.

Comment: You should first apply all the filters, then paginate. Now you're first paginating and applying the filter to a `Page` object.

Comment: Wow thanks, now it works, i didnt know it was so easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only filter a `QuerySet`. But in your view, you're first paginating (so `products` is now a `Page`) and then trying filter that `Page` object. You should only paginate *after* you've got your final `QuerySet` with all filters applied.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Filter options for invoice list table -->
<div class="hidden">
    {% if ordered_by %}
        <!-- ordered_by is a custom context data from get context method -->
        <input type="hidden" id="pre-order" value="{{ ordered_by }}" disabled>
    {% endif %}
    
    {% if is_paginated %}
        <input type="hidden" id="page-no" value="{{ page_obj.number }}" disabled>
    {% endif %}
    <input type="hidden" id="current-url" value="{% url 'InvoiceList' %}" disabled>
</div>


<div class="my-2 py-2 row">
    <div class="btn-group-sm d-flex align-items-center col-md-4 my-2" style="column-gap: 5px">
        {% if is_paginated %}
            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <a class="btn btn-outline-darkcherry" href="?page=1{% if ordered_by %}&ordering={{ ordered_by }}{% endif %}"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i></a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-darkcherry" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}{% if ordered_by %}&ordering={{ ordered_by }}{% endif %}"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-angles-left"></i></a>
            {% endif %}

            {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
                {% if page_obj.number == num %}
                    <a class="btn btn-darkcherry" href="?page={{ num }}{% if ordered_by %}&ordering={{ ordered_by }}{% endif %}">{{ num }}</a>
                {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-darkcherry" href="?page={{ num }}{% if ordered_by %}&ordering={{ ordered_by }}{% endif %}">{{ num }}</a>
                {% endif %}
                {% if num > page_obj.number|add:'-1' and num < page_obj.number|add:'1' %}
                    <span class="bg-creamy btn fw-lighter"> of {{ paginator.num_pages }}</span>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <a class="btn btn-outline-darkcherry" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}{% if ordered_by %}&ordering={{ ordered_by }}{% endif %}"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-angles-right"></i></a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-darkcherry" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}{% if ordered_by %}&ordering={{ ordered_by }}{% endif %}"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i></a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

**See this html template**
here i get a context data on the top inside a container class **hidden** from get_context_data method to change the "href" of the sorter button.

```
var pagehref = null;
const pre_order = $("#pre-order").val();
const url = $("#current-url").val();

if($("#page-no")) {
    const page_no = $("#page-no").val();
    pagehref = `page=${page_no}&`;
}

$('#sort-name').ready(function() {
    var $this, addClass, href;

    if(pre_order == "customer_id") {
        href = `${url}?${pagehref}ordering=-customer_id`;
        addClass = "fa-solid fa-sort-up";
        $this = $(this);
    } else if(pre_order == "-customer_id") {
        href = `${url}?${pagehref}`;
        addClass = "fa-solid fa-sort-down";
        $this = $(this);
    } else {
        href = `${url}?${pagehref}ordering=customer_id`;
        addClass = "fa-solid fa-sort";
        $this = $(this);
    }
    $('#sort-name').find('.fa-solid').removeClass().addClass(addClass);
    $('#sort-name').attr('href', href);
});



$('#sort-date').ready(function() {
    var $this, addClass, href; 

    if(pre_order == "created_date") {
        href = `${url}?${pagehref}ordering=-created_date`;
        addClass = "fa-solid fa-sort-up";
        $this = $(this);
    } else if(pre_order == "-created_date") {
        href = `${url}?${pagehref}`;
        addClass = "fa-solid fa-sort-down";
        $this = $(this);
    } else {
        href = `${url}?${pagehref}ordering=created_date`;
        addClass = "fa-solid fa-sort";
        $this = $(this);
    }
    $('#sort-date').find('.fa-solid').removeClass().addClass(addClass);
    $('#sort-date').attr('href', href);
});
```

This my jQuery code to change the href link when ever the page load it get the paginator data and ordered by data and combine it with & to pass multiple parametes in url.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(InvoiceListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['total_invoices'] = self.model.objects.all().count()
    context['ordered_by'] = self.get_ordering()
    return context

def get_ordering(self):
    order = self.request.GET.get('ordering', None)
    return order
```

This is my ListView mehtods